# Is a mathematical statement uniquely determined by all of its necessary conditions?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

The question I have is basically the one in the title: if I fix a statement $P$, is the set of all conditions $\{X_i\}$ necessary for $P$ to be true enough information for me to recover $P$?

An attempt to make the question more precise is as follows. Fix a formula $P$ in some language $\mathcal{L}$. Given a set of formulas $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ such that the set $\{P\rightarrow X_i\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ is maximally consistent, can I determine $P$ uniquely up to logical equivalence?

As an example where this is true, consider the first order language $\mathcal{L}_\text{NT}$ of number theory, and the following two statements

$$X_1 \equiv \text{"$x$ is even"} \quad X_2 \equiv \text{"$x$ is prime"}.$$

from these necessary conditions, I can determine that, for any set of conditions $\{X_i\}$ containing $X_1$ and $X_2$, if all $\{P\rightarrow X_i\}$ are simultaneously satisfied, then, up to logical equivalence, we have $P \equiv \text{"$x = 2$"}$.

Comment: In your example, can't we also have $P(x) \equiv \bot$?

Comment: Per Curry-Howard isomorphism's *proposition as set (type)*, your concerned statement P's existence and uniqueness can be immediately assured by [axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) which is a critical axiom of set theory which says *there always exists a set B (a subset of A designed to resolve Russell paradox) such that given any set x, x is a member of B if and only if x is a member of A and any formula φ holds for x.* You can repeatedly invoke the schema to apply to each of your $X_i$, the final set B is your $P$ which may be ⊥ if B=∅.

Comment: ...but from your informal description in your first paragraph you want "the set of all conditions {Xi} necessary for P to be *true* enough information for me to recover P", and later you also talked about "maximally consistent" which is not like the same as in your title and we need further clarification. Per completeness theorem, if your P is supposed to be always true in the beginning by its definite description, then we can always find a proof via its Xi's, not sure what do you mean recover in this case... Btw, Russell analyzed about proper/improper definite descriptions in general...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to provable equivalence, the answer is "yes"!

Every first order theory can be associated to a [syntactic category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/syntactic+category) where formulas $\varphi(x_1, \ldots x_n)$ correspond to subobjects of an object $X^n$ (here you should think of $X$ as the "underlying set" of a "free model" of your theory. Then the formula $\varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is exactly the subobject $\{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid \varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \} \subseteq X^n$. This is a little white lie, but is morally correct).

Now the (definable) subobjects of $X^n$ (up to provable equivalence) form a lattice, and $\phi \leq \psi$ happens if and only if $\phi \vdash \psi$! Now what does yoneda's lemma tell us for this lattice? It says exactly that $\psi$ is determined up to isomorphism (that is, up to provable equivalence) by elements below $\psi$.

So $\psi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is determined up to provable equivalence by

$$
\{ \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \vdash \psi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \}
$$

Or, if you like,

$$
\{ \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \to \psi(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \}
$$

since $\phi \vdash \psi$ implies $\phi \to \psi$ is the top element of the lattice (True).

For more info, you might be interested in Steve Awodey's lecture notes [here](https://github.com/awodey/CatLogNotes/blob/master/catlog2.pdf).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Gödel's first incompleteness theorems shows that a particular statement G, the Gödel sentence of PA, is not provable nor disprovable in PA. By the completeness theorem, this means that G is false in all non-standard models of PA while G is true in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$. So seems a statement defined by all its necessary conditions may not be unique up to *logical equivalence*. How your categorical logic can explain this?

Comment: @mohottnad "G is false in all non-standard models of PA while G is true in the standard model". No, you misunderstand the incompleteness theorem. Every sentence which is true in the standard model (including G) is also true in some non-standard models. But anyway, I don't see the connection between your comment and HallaSurvivor's answer (which seems totally correct to me). Can you clarify the point you're trying to make?

Comment: @AlexKruckman thx for your critique. Yes you're right that I should've said "G is false in some non-standard models" not "all non-standard models". However, G by construction is a statement certainly definitely described by all its necessary conditions (is not a vague or ill-defined or undefinable statement/sentence). From what I understood from OP's informal description, he or she is concerned with the uniqueness of the truth value of such a statement. So I just listed a counterexample.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: I think you may have answered the wrong question. The OP is *not* asking whether the set of all consequences of a statement determines the statement.

Comment: @AndrejBauer -- I'm not sure I understand what OP is asking, if not what I answered. If you left an answer of your own, it might clarify things for me as well, and I would happily upvote it ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I believe you answered the question of whether $P$ is determined from $\{X_i | X_i \rightarrow P\}$, whereas I was asking about whether $P$ is determined from $\{X_i | P \rightarrow X_i\}$.  I only have very elementary knowledge of category theory, but is it perhaps possible to reverse your argument (i.e: "by the Yoneda lemma, $\psi$ is determined up to provable equivalence by elements above $\psi$")?

Comment: @Solarflare0 -- yes, the same argument works for $\{X_i \mid P \to X_i\}$, or as I was writing, $\{ \phi \mid \psi \to \phi \}$. The only difference is whether we use the covariant or contravariant version of the yoneda lemma.

Comment: Well, the OP accepted the answer. But they didn't speak of the set of all consequences of $P$. They said: given a family $(X_i)_i$ such that $\{P \to X_i \mid i\}$ is *maximally consistent*, is $P$ uniquely determined? Let me put it this way: why isn't your answer mentioning maximal consistency at all?

Answer (score 3):

I like the category-theoretic perspective in HallaSurvivor's answer, but let me give a more "down to earth" version of the same argument, which might help some readers.

Fix an $L$-sentence $P$. Let $N = \{Q\mid Q\text{ is an $L$-sentence, and }P\vdash Q\}$, the set of all $L$-sentences which are necessary for $P$. I claim that $P$ can be recovered, up to logical equivalence, from $N$. Indeed, $P$ is characterized up to logical equivalence as the sentence in $N$ with the property that it is *sufficient* for every sentence in $N$. That is, by the following properties:
(1) $X\in N$, and (2) for all $Q\in N$, $X\vdash Q$.

First note that $P$ satisfies (1) and (2). For (1), $P\vdash P$, so $P\in N$. For (2), for all $Q\in N$, $P\vdash Q$ by definition of $N$.

Now suppose $P'$ satisfies (1) and (2). I claim that $P'$ is logically equivalent to $P$. By (1), $P'\in N$, so $P\vdash P'$. And since $P\in N$, by (2), $P'\vdash P$. So $P$ and $P'$ are logically equivalent.

---

I believe this answers the question as you have stated it in your title and first paragraph. Unfortunately, the rest of what you wrote (in particular, the "attempt to make the question more precise") makes little sense to me. Here are some clarifying questions:

- In the title question, you talk about *all* conditions necessary for $P$. But in the later paragraphs, you look at an arbitrary set of conditions $X_i$ which are necessary for $P$. Which one did you mean?
- What exactly do you mean by "the set $\{P\rightarrow X_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ is maximally consistent"? A set of conditional sentences of this form will never be a maximally consistent (i.e., complete) theory unless $P$ is logically valid. But maybe you meant maximally consistent among sets of sentences of this form? Note that (unless $P$ is valid), *any* set of sentences of this form is consistent, since they're all true when $P$ is false.
- In the next paragraph, you switch out "the set $\{P\rightarrow X_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ is maximally consistent" for "the set $\{P\rightarrow X_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ is simultaneously satisfied". As Andrej Bauer points out in the comments, there's another possibility where $P\rightarrow X_1$ and $P\rightarrow X_2$ are simultaneously satisfied, namely when $P$ is contradictory: $\bot$, or $x\neq x$.

Comment: Issue regarding first required property of your constructed set $N$ above, e.g., $P$ states that *$P$ is the set of all normal sets* (a normal set is not a member of itself), and each $X_i$ simply states *the $ith$ element of $P$ is a normal set*, then $P$ satisfies both properties of your constructed set $N$ since each $X_i$ is a necessary consequence of $P$. But per Russell's paradox there's no such $P$ at all, so you cannot determine the truth value of $P$ up to logical equivalence. It seems you need to restrict your comprehension of $N$ like the axiom schema of specification of ZFC...

Comment: @mohottnad I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. $P$ is an $L$-sentence, not a set. For any fixed language $L$, there is a set $S$ of all $L$-sentences, and there is a "provable entailment" relation $\vdash$ on $S$. For a fixed $P\in S$, my set $N$ is $\{Q\in S\mid P\vdash Q\}$. This no more complicated than writing down the set $\{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid 5\leq n\}$.

Comment: Thx for your near instant feedback and counter-critique. I don't see any problem to construct an $L$-sentence $P$ using following infinite conjunction normal form "$X_1 \land X_2...\land X_i \land...$", where each $X_i$ is an $L$-sentence says "This sentence proves a certain set $Y_i$ constructed in such a ... way is normal." Also 
per Curry-Howard correspondence a sentence (proposition) can be rightly viewed as a well formed set (type), find an element of a specified well defined set is equivalent (isomorphic) to find a proof of its corresponding proposition (an $L$-sentence)...

Comment: @mohottnad My secret is that I get notifications on my phone when someone comments! I'm afraid I don't understand what your sentences $X_i$ are supposed to mean or why any of this is relevant to the question at hand. I have given a very simple proof - if you think it's not correct, it would be more productive to point to a specific place in the proof where you think it goes wrong, rather than trying to describe the rather complicated counterexample you have in mind. Also, I would forget about set theory here and just think about propositional logic, which is enough to understand my answer.

Comment: Ah I'm not sure if your secret is good or bad for you (there's no definition of good, bad, or foolish in math so there won't be any formal proof for you personally here.), and I'm not sure if you like type theory interpretation (model) of this problem... Let me move to another possible doubt about your confident *sufficient* conclusion to determine $P$'s truth value merely from its *necessary* conditions alone which smells like ontological argument of the existence of God (Leibniz's theodicy and his principle of sufficient reason?).

Comment: Formally per Goedel we have N⊨Con(PA) & PA⊬Con(PA), so from the intuitive standard PA model N all our elementary school arithmetic results are necessarily true (not in vain) but the sentence Con(PA) still cannot be fixed up to logical equivalence... Also note in OP's example they use $X_1$≡"x is even", $X_2$≡"x is prime", so clearly they're thinking in terms of elementary set building (possibly causing later maximal consistency confusion), not your pure proposition entailments in a meta formal system. I just feel this general problem is interesting and can be discussed with many angles...

Comment: Here's another simple counterexample. Let $X_1$≡"x is even", $X_2$≡"x is square", then $P$≡"x is 4 or 16 or...". Let $P'=X_1 \land X_2 \land W$≡"x is 4" where $W$≡"x is less than 10", then $P' ⊢ X_i$ where i=1,2 and $P' ⊢ P$. However, P ⊬ P' as claimed in your proof and clearly P and P' are not logically equivalent. The defect in your proof is after you first fix a sentence $P$ to build your set $N$, you just confine any competing P' within $N$, but my above simple example P' clearly in not a member of your $N$. Using axiom schema of specification of ZFC seems the clearest way to specify $P$..

Comment: @mohottnad You have misread my proof. My claim that $P$ and $P'$ are logically equivalent is under the assumptions I called (1) and (2). Note that (1) says $P'\in N$, i.e. that $P\vdash P'$. Your choice of $P'$ violates this assumption. Also, I have no idea how you think the axiom schema of specification in ZFC is relevant to specifying a sentence or a formula in some logic. If you think you have a better approach to the OP's question, I think it will be more constructive at this point for you to write your own answer instead of continuing to comment on mine.